# PowerShell Script error while setting credentials using Set-Credential command

Tags: powershell

We have multiple powershell script where we set credentials, this was working since last 2 years without any issue and suddenly below code start throwing an error. It is performing operations but still throwing error. Not able to figure out what causing the error. Please help if anyone has seen this before.

```
$UserName='<>'
$Password='<>'


# ************* SET CREDENTIALS ******************************************

$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$global:Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$Password)
Set-CdmCredential -Domain (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain -Credential $Cred
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if those creds actually work (account could have expired or had password reset etc)? Not familiar with `Set-CmdCredential` - assuming that is your own code, could be further clues in there?

Comment: The error says the user name or password is no good so I would start there. Like @MisterSmith said, Set-CmdCredential is not a native PowerShell Cmdlet. As a matter of fact, a quick Google search of the term brought up a result of another question you posted here 2 years ago using the exact same Cmdlet. Without knowing the code used to make that Cmdlet/Function, there really is no substance here for anyone to help you beyond that error message.

Comment: Are you talking about the 'Set-CdmCredential' cmdlet that comes with Centrify products? (https://www.centrify.com/)

Comment: @ZivkoKozarov yes we use centrify commands and scripts to perform some operations. Same commands and script were working since last 2 years but suddenly started throwing above error. Any other option to set credentials for Centrify? Could not find enough documentation around it.